# Windows 10 Shutdown confirmation between specific times

Tags: windows-10, powershell, group-policy

I want to display a confirmation dialog when I try to shutdown my PC before a specific time in the day.

I tried already adding a PowerShell script in the `Local Group Policy Editor` to `Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts -> Shutdown` in the tabs `Scripts` as well as `PowerShell Scripts` and manually copied it to the folder that opens when I click `Show Files...`

But it seems like the script isn't getting started or the message box get's closed right away by Windows. This is the script:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$now = Get-Date
$deadline = Get-Date -Hour 16 -Minute 30 -Second 0
if ($now -lt $deadline) {
$answer = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Continue Shutdown?","Shutdown", "YesNo" , "Information" , "Button1")
if ($answer -eq "No") {
    shutdown -a
}
}
```

Activating `Shutdown Event Tracker` isn't an option as I can't specify the times.

Currently the only solution I see is having a custom shutdown script I use instead of the Windows Shutdown Button.
Do you have any other idea?

Comment: What happens if you make the messagebox TopMost `$answer = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($null, "Continue Shutdown?","Shutdown", "YesNo" , "Information" , "Button1")` ? Or use a different one Modally: `Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic; $answer = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox("Continue Shutdown?", "YesNo,SystemModal,Information", "Shutdown")`